# Contributing to Numpy on Pypy

Tags: open-source, numpy, scipy, pypy

I'm looking to put some work in on numpy on pypy. I'm a huge Python fan, and to have it move toward an actual option in the world of numerical/scientific computing is huge for me. It's obviously got a ways to go, but if you don't need C-level optimization, it's going to be much prettier to develop.

I'm doing some digging around on the site and on Google, but I'm only finding links to donate. Where should I start to actually contribute directly to implementing numpy in pypy?

Thanks

Comment: [Just ask them.](http://pypy.org/contact.html)

Comment: In any case be sure to write comprehensive tests too, they are quite avid TDD users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get started it to either join us in the #pypy channel on freenode, or to send a message to the pypy-dev mailing list!